# How to put the JSON to a store(DOJO)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the JSON data as the following from a 
URL(http://a.b.c.d:8080/myWS/services/GetIcDetail/IcView)

```
[
{
    "Name": "A",
    "order": "1",
    "dir": "In",
    "pName": "1/2"
},
{
    "Name": "A",
    "order": "2",
    "dir": "Out",
    "pName": "1/2"
},
{
    "Name": "CWR8-88",
    "order": "4",
    "dir": "Out",
    "pName": "1/3/OMD"
},
{
    "Name": "11DPM12",
    "order": "5",
    "dir": "In",
    "pName": "1/5/L1"
}
]
```

How can i put this JSON data to a store in DOJO?

**EDIT**

JSON data is formatted and validated. You can edit your validate your json [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: You've tagged your question as Java, but when you say "DOJO", do you mean the *JavaScript* [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/)? Java and JavaScript are not the same thing. Also, the JSON you've posted is invalid in several ways.

Answer (score 0):

To utilize the module, require in the module, create a new instance.

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRest){
  var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "/some/resource"
  });

  // Store an object identified by identity
  store.put({
    foo: "bar"
  }, {
    id: 3
  });

  // Remove an object by ID
  store.remove(3);
});
```